# Function Visibility Causing Memory Leak

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks

My application A is explicitly linking my .so libraries B1, B2, etc. using shared internal API. It loops over all of them and uses dlopen() followed by dlclose(). Libraries Bx statically link many libraries, one of them being Caffe. To properly free all allocated memory (global variables), I need to call a function google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary(). The Bx use restriction on export table symbols (I am calling this file exportmap, i.e. -Wl,--version-script=exportmap) to specify functions to export to the customers, only function from internal API are allowed to be visible globaly. All of it is written in C++.

1) The problem is that if I use this setup and I do an endless loop in the program A:

```
while(1) {
  forall B in Bx { // loop over filepaths to .so libraries Bx
    hdl = dlopen(B, RTLD_LAZY);
    dlclose(hdl);
}}
```

the program will incrementaly leak memory (memory raises until it crashes).

2) If I don't use exportmap on Bx, then the program is not leaking any memory, but that is true just in case there is no more than 1 library Bx. If I insert 2 or more different Bx than the incremental memory leak is present again.

3) If I use RTLD_NODELETE flag in dlopen function in the program A:

```
while(1) {
  forall B in Bx {
    hdl = dlopen(B, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_NODELETE)
    dlclose(hdl);
}}
```

and I disable calling google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary() in the Bx libraries than there is no incrementaly raising memory leak, but there will be stuff left behind in the protobuf, therefore this option is the best so far, but still not ideal.

Can anybody explain, how is it possible, that exportmap can cause memory leak and possibly, how to solve this issue without any memory leaks?

Comment: What is that language? It isn't C++ as far as I see, unless you somehow defined some macros to make `forall Bx {` valid ...

Comment: @L. F. The application is written in C++, the code here is mixed C++ and pseudocode, to avoid unrelated code I used endless as while(1), and forall Bx as a loop, which gives filepaths to .so libraries Bx.

Comment: maybe one of your dll's allocates on load, doesn't free it on unload.  But there's no way that we can possibly find out

Comment: @UKMonkey That would not explain, why there is no memory leak in case 2) because I have tried it on every single .so library with the same behaviour.